# It with plural words

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

Can I use "It" with plural words?
For example, "It can be short stories or classic product descriptions" or it is better to say "These can be short stories or classic product descriptions"

Comment: What does "it" refer to? What's the preceding context? Is the referent a singular or plural noun?

Answer (score 2):

"It" is singular... but in your example, "it" doesn't appear to be referring to anything plural.

For example:

> Tell me your **favourite thing** to read. **It** can be short stories or classic product descriptions.

In this example, "it" refers to the singular *favourite thing*. 'Short stories', although plural, is being used as a *genre* or *type* or reading material.

The only thing I don't understand is who reads product descriptions like they read short stories...

Comment: Thank you)) Here I'm talking about the ways one can tell about the product. It can be short stories or classic product descriptions.

Comment: "Ways" is plural. Remember, "it" refers to something *previously mentioned* (or immediately apparent). So look back at what you've asked for. If it is plural, then "it" is wrong.

Comment: So I can say, "Description is a third point that catches customers' attention. It can be short stories or classic product descriptions." Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @mila well, your "it" refers back to 'description', which is singular so that bit is correct at least. But you're saying that 'description' can be short stories of classic product descriptions... I have no idea what that could mean. Unless 'description' is being used as jargon for some singular or collective thing that I don't comprehend, I don't understand how singular description can be plural descriptions. Hopefully you know what you're talking about.